# Algorithm for finding a single number to represent two different numerical scales?

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, math

I'm looking for an algorithm to combine two values;

- Where the first value indicates a positive result when the value is higher. For example, 0.98 is 'good' and 0.15 is 'bad'.

  - Where the second value indicates a positive result when the value is lower. For example, 10,000 is 'bad', whereas 1000 is 'good'.

I need a method of determining a value that can represent both of these scales with one number, so that I can sort my findings on my application from high to low accordingly. I'm not sure if anyone knows of such an algorithm, or any advice, but any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

P.S. I am aware I can 'negate' one of the two values, to have them appear on a similar scale, however I'm not sure how this would work in Java.

EDIT: Sorry, so to elaborate, I'm sorting images based on similarity to a user input image. Each of my algorithms that I'm using to return a value of similarity, function on a different scale. The first being a value between 0.00 and 1.00, with numbers being closer to 1.00, indicating the image is more similar to the original. Whereas, my second algorithm returns values from 1000+, with higher values indicating the image is *less* similar to the original. I need to take these two values and combine them to allow me to sort the resulting images in order of similarity, with the most similar image being shown at the top of my list, and the least similar at the bottom. Hopefully this helps clear up any confusion. Thanks again.

Comment: didn't understand the question

Comment: You're not sure how negate would work in Java?!?!?

Comment: What do you mean by "sort my findings ... from high to low accordingly"?  There's a _lot_ of missing information.  Please provide some examples that would help us see what _pairs_ of numbers you would consider higher than other pairs, and why.

Comment: Do you need to find the two values closest to your target value or what?

Comment: Your edit only partly clears up the confusion.  I still don't know enough about your data.  Are the measurements equally accurate, so that the two can be weighted equally, or should one be given more weight than the other?  Should they be treated as linear functions?  As the answer says, you'll need to come up with a function to represent the similarity.  But without knowing anything about your measurements or how they work, we can't write a decent function for you.

Comment: Yes, they're equally accurate, equally weighted, just different values used for representing similarity. Each of the values returns numerical data based on the different descriptors its evaluating, so I essentially need an 'average' of sorts, of the two, which is why I need both to be on the same scale, so I can average them, to then be able to sort. Sorry about all the confusion, I'm finding it really hard to explain the situation haha!

Comment: If they should be weighted equally, then just adjust the scales so that the two values are on the same scale.  If one value goes from 0 to _x_, and the other value goes from 0 to _y_, then divide the first value by _x_ and the second by _y_ so that they both go from 0 to 1, then take the average.  (And if one goes in reverse, take the negative, or subtract it from 1.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your only goal is sorting, you need to come up with a function `g(x,y)` that represents the "goodness" of your pair of values. A pair (x1,y1) is better than (x2,y2) if and only if g(x1,y1) > g(x2,y2).

The function must represent what you consider "good". A simple example would be:

```
g(x,y) = x - y / 10000
```